# Function dilemma with keystrokes not recognizing

Tags: python, function, pygame

So I have this problem of the code within the function not recognizing the keystrokes of my UP, DOWN, LEFT and DOWN keys and I wonder why. Can't seem to fix this. I need this to work somehow so i can use the same code in another part of the program I'm coding.

```
def movementVariables():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #testkey
            #if event.key == K_SPACE:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = True
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = True
                moveUp = False
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False

WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400

moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVE_SPEED = 0

levelOne = True
while levelOne == True:
        if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            player.top += MOVE_SPEED
        if moveUp and player.top > 0:
            player.top -= MOVE_SPEED
        if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
            player.left -= MOVE_SPEED
        if moveRight and player.right < WINDOW_WIDTH:
            player.right += MOVE_SPEED
```

I tried to post as little code as possible so I don't overflow with useless code. Just type if you need the whole code.

Comment: I have a difficulty setting screen which change the `MOVE_SPEED` value between the choices of 5,7,9, and it the `MOVE_SPEED = 0` keeps the object at a standstill when not pressing the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moveUp`, `moveDown` etc are local variables in your function `movementVariables`, and they are assigned during the function then abandoned when it finishes. You need to use the outer scope variables explicitly:

```
def movementVariables():
    global moveUp
    global moveDown
    global moveLeft
    global moveRight
```

Or, better, actually `return` and use something from the function:

```
def movementVariables():
    ...
    return movement
```